Assign Grid.Column or Grid.Row by name in WPF?
As far as I know, the common way to define WPF Grid Columns/Rows is using Column definition and declare as many as you want with their Width/Height :
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!--do something here--> 
        <Button Grid.Column="0"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1"/>
    </Grid>

If I now decide to insert a new column between 0 and 1, I have to go back to all reference to 1 (and subsequent columns) and remap them manually. Surely there must be a better way ?
Can I declare a name to my column definition <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" x:Name="ButtonColumn"/> and reference this new name instead of the column index ? Any other trick that allows me to insert/delete column without having to replace all indices would do, many thanks !

There are many Controls having this behaviour like StackPanel DockPanel WrapPanel, why are you trying to create your own?

@MustafaMutasim fair point, width and height distribution works differently with stack & dock panels. Setting a specific column width to * is a good way for me to control where I want the extra space.
Same goes for certain control sizes, text box background inside a grid for example...

@SirRufo I guess it does! looks a bit deeper than I would have liked, but it's there :)

Workaround:
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid x:Name="GridColumn_0" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <Grid x:Name="GridColumn_1" Grid.Column="1"/>
</Grid>

From Code-Behind:
Button Mybutton = new Button();
TextBox MyTextBox = new TextBox();

GridColumn_0.Children.Add(Mybutton);
GridColumn_1.Children.Add(MyTextBox );

